# Dropbox login using mechanize Python

Tags: python, dropbox, mechanize

I'm trying to login to Dropbox (dropbox.com/login) via mechanize on Python.
I think I'm missing something as the response returns as HTTP Forbidden 403 Error.

This is the code I used:

```
import mechanize


url = "https://www.dropbox.com/login"
email = "<USERNAME>"
password = "<PASSWORD>"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_gzip(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(False)
br.set_handle_referer(False)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.addheaders = [('Host', 'www.dropbox.com')]
br.addheaders = [('Connection', 'keep-alive')]
#br.addheaders = [('Content-Length', '7385')]
br.addheaders = [('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', 1)]
br.addheaders = [('Origin', 'https://www.dropbox.com')]
br.addheaders = [('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')]
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36')]
br.addheaders = [('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8')]
br.addheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
charset=UTF-8')]
br.addheaders = [('Referer', 'https://www.dropbox.com/login? 
cont=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dropbox.com')]
br.addheaders = [('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br')]
br.addheaders = [('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.9')]
br.addheaders = [('Cookie', '<COOKIE DATA>')]

response = br.open(url)
try:
    formcount=0
    for frm in br.forms():  
      if str(frm.attrs["class"])=="clearfix credentials-form login-form":
        break
      formcount=formcount+1
    br.select_form(nr=formcount)
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
except:
    print("Unable to find login form.");
    exit(1);


br.form['login_email'] = email
br.form['login_password'] = password

response = br.submit(nr = formcount)
print response.text
```

And this is the response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 51, in <module>
    response = br.submit(nr = formcount)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 685, in 
submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 254, in 
open
    return self._mech_open(url_or_request, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 310, in 
_mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I know I'm missing something but can't figure out what.
*I'll note that I copied the headers from an intercepted request I made in the browser.
I know there's an SDK for Dropbox API, but I need to scrape the website..

Thanks in advance,
Amit.

Comment: I suspect that *forbidden* means exactly what it says. DropBox provides an API, and I imagine that this is intended to force you to use the API.

Comment: I can understand that, but still.. I mean, there has to be a way to get around it and I'm guessing it's headers and hidden fields related. As hidden fields remain unchanged in my code, and I've copied all headers - there's must be something I'm missing

Comment: I'm now beginning to realize that it may has to do with the form POSTing via AJAX, something which mechanize can't handle.. bummer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting/scraping the Dropbox web site is a violation of [the Dropbox terms](https://www.dropbox.com/terms#acceptable_use). Regardless, I wouldn't recommend doing so anyway, as it's subject to change without notice and so your code would be likely to break.

[Dropbox does offer an extensive API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) though, which hopefully offers whatever functionality you're looking for, as well as [an official Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python). I recommend using that instead.

If the API doesn't offer what you need, please let us know and we'll log it as a feature request.

Comment: I completly understand where you're coming from and I would try to parse the HTML page if there was a suitable API option.
As I'm trying to access account information via APi, I have to resort to parsing plain HTML.. :\

Comment: @doria90 What account information specifically do you need? Does the [`FullAccount`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.users.FullAccount) object returned by [`users_get_current_account`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.users_get_current_account) not offer it?